# Javascript/AngularJS: Check if an element has the style overflow-y applied to it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to check inside my code if a  has applied to its css styling the attribute overflow-y: auto. For example if my  has a class "abcd", and "abcd" has for its css overflow-y: auto, then the  passes. While I've already found a method for jquery, which I am not using, I want to find a method for pure javascript (or Angular JS) to find if the element has a given css attribute. How can I do this without jquery?

Comment: well, in Angular, if your element can (or not) have CSS applied depends whether it has (or not) a certain class. For instance, if the element has an `.overflow` class, then it will be applied `overflow-y:auto` in your CSS. Now, whether this particular element has this class or not depends on a variable in your script : `hasOverflowClass = true`, therefore you know which CSS is applied. In Angular, you don't read the DOM like jQuery does. You construct it, so you have all the info you need before the DOM is even built.

Comment: See [MDN WEB API Reference - `Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getComputedStyle` method available on the `window` object.

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');
var overflowValue = getComputedStyle(MyElement).overflowY;
if (overflowValue == 'auto') {
  // your code here
}
```

This method will get values of css properties applied in the moment.

For more info, you can refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

hope that helps.

Comment: Oh this worked pretty nice and did exactly what I needed it to do. Thank you and to @magus both for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

You can check with pure javascript by using this code : `document.getElementById('myElement').style['overflow-y']`.

The issue is that this code will works only for inline css style, as in `<div style="overflow-y: visible">...</div>`. If the css style comes from a class, you can't find it like this.

The jQuery `css` method will find the computed style (so it can detect the real value of `overflow-y` even if it comes from a class). But the `css` code is very huge. You can find it here : https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js

I want to add that checking if an element has a specific css style is a very bad smell.

Instead of this, you should really consider to check if the element has a specific class. Or if you have using angularjs, a simple boolean in the model will do the trick.

If you really want to check if an element has the `overflow-y: auto;` style applied, according to the jQuery code, they use `window.getComputedStyle(element)`. They also have a lot of code with a temporary div with a weird position (`position:absolute;left:-11111px;width:60px;`) but it is mostly to support old browsers like IE8 and IE9.

In your case, something like this could works : `window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('myElement'))['overflow-y'] === 'auto'`.

Comment: I know that such checking isn't exactly the best solution, but the project I am working on is very big and has lots of already bad choices in its code. Since this check will apply to many kinds of <div> in different html structures, simply changing to overflow-y in inline isn't a good solution for the current state of the project. And since jquery shouldn't be used, the only solution I have is to check if overflow exists in a class. And for it to work without changing tens of html files it must be done in code.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to dig in the jQuery `css` code to know how they achieve that.